# mongoid: what is the diff between building and creating within embedded one to one relations

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

Given [embedded one to one](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-1.html) mongoid doc, I can't really get the difference between building and creating actions.

Here what they state:

```
building and creating

From the parent side, documents in the embedded child can be initialized or created using the specially defined methods.

# Create a new child name given the provided attributes.
person.build_name(vorname: "Heinrich", nachname: "Heine")

# Create a persisted child name.
person.create_name(vorname: "Heinrich", nachname: "Heine")
```

... can anyone enlight the diff ?
Thanks in advance
luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `create_name`, you're saving the embedded object to the server. When you call `build_name` you're just initializing the embedded model, you still need to call save.

This only applies if the parent document has been saved to the server already, otherwise `create_name` functions exactly like `build_name`.

For example:

```
person = Person.first
person.build_name(vorname: "Foo", nachname: "Bar")
person.name.save
```

and

```
person = Person.first
person.create_name(vorname: "Foo", nachname: "Bar")
```

Are the same thing.